# Comparação entre FTP e HTTP para transferência de arquivos

Tags: http, ftp, redes

Uma questão que me intriga é sobre a transferência de arquivos binários pela internet.

Tenho experiência no uso de FTP, o qual eventualmente passava por problemas de firewall nos clientes. Outra questão defendida pelos sysadmins era quanto a falta de segurança deste protocolo.

Frente a isso existe a alternativa do HTTP, que resolve a dificuldade com firewall.
Mas em relação a segurança, performance, limitações, quais as **vantagens** e **desvantagens** entre FTP e HTTP?

Faz sentido optar por FTP, em detrimento do HTTP?

Comment: Se o problema passa pela falta de segurança em relação ao FTP, podes optar por sftp: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-utilizar-o-sftp-para-transferir-arquivos-com-seguranca-com-um-servidor-remoto-pt

Comment: HTTP não foi criado para transferência de arquivos binários (embora seja capaz disso), então, se o foco é esse, não é o protocolo mais adequado.

Comment: @bfavaretto Mas e os problemas do FTP? A amazon, com o serviço utilizado em larga escala S3, não utiliza justo o HTTP para comunicação?

Comment: @bfavaretto Ops. Não utiliza o FTP.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart apesar de "parecido", S3 não é um sistema de arquivos (tampouco tem conceito de diretórios). É mera associação objeto <-> chave. FTP não foi feito para trabalhar fora de filesystems. Não teria muito sentido adaptar o protocolo simplesmente para "imitar" o comportamento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caro,
O FTP foi criado exclusivamente com o propósito de transferir arquivos, a grande vantagem deste protocolo sobre o HTTP é a possibilidade da transferência em "mão dupla" sem necessidade de desenvolvimento, de maneira nativa, se você está em dúvida em relação aos 2 acredito que sua necessidade seja a de disponibilizar os arquivos e os seus clientes farão apenas o download sem realizar nenhum upload.

Em questão de segurança os dois são semelhantes, ex: com relação à ataques do tipo *man-in-the-middle* os 2 terão desempenho similar, já que a transferência se dá basicamente em texto plano(sem criptografia) nos 2 casos e pode ser facilmente interceptada, o que pode ser contornado com o sFTP(ssh) como mencionado pelo @Miguel ou com FTPS(SSL) .

Acredito que em 99% dos casos o que dita a tecnologia a ser utilizada é a necessidade final, sendo assim:

Se necessita apenas enviar arquivos, e estes arquivos não são sensíveis (não confidenciais) eu optaria sem dúvida ao HTTP pelo motivo que você especificou, não há problemas com firewall dos clientes.

Se seus dados são confidenciais optaria pelo sFTP(ssh) ou pelo FTPS(SSL), devidamente configurados (usuário anonimo desabilitado, senhas fortes, etc..).

Além destas opções existe ainda um meio termo, que é utilizar uma plataforma de troca de arquivos segura por HTTPS, implantei recentemente num cliente e tem atendido de forma plena: https://pydio.com/

Comment: FTP foi feito pra transferir arquivo: correto - HTTP não ser mao dupla: incorreto (metodos POST e PUT, por exemplo)- FTP tem user e senha e HTTP não: incorreto (HTTP pode usar autenticação usuário/senha sem problemas, direto no protocolo) - Texto plano nos 2 casos: incorreto (FTP trabalha com binário sem problemas) - Sugiro arrumar os 3 pontos incorretos (há outras afirmações meio complicadas, mas esses 3 pontos realmente merecem uma correção).

Comment: @Bacco - ok caro! já editei a resposta para ficar mais clara, quanto à "mão dupla" [pra exemplificar](http://download.dominiosistemas.com.br/atualizacao/), (considerando desenvolvimento zero)

Comment: @GustavoFast Por que grandes players de cloud, como a amazon, com o serviço utilizado em larga escala S3, não utiliza justo o FTP para comunicação?

Comment: eu acho que o ftp praticamente morreu, é muito pouco utilizado